# an editor for specman

Tags: emacs, editor, vi, specman

I started working with specman recently and I am looking for a good editor for my code.

I am used to working with vi and Emacs - if there is any add-on that can help with one of those, that would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Google is your friend. First hit for "emacs specman": http://www.verisity.com/specman-mode.html

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the Emacs/XEmacs specman-mode from https://github.com/hackonteur/specman-mode. We will continue to improve it and you are welcome to contribute.

Answer (score 1):

There is a Specman mode for Emacs. It used to be available here http://www.specman-mode.com but now it moved to Cadence here http://www.cadence.com/Community/error.htm?aspxerrorpath=/community/forums/T/28436.aspx

Note: At the time of posting the link didn't work, but I checked it out about 5 days before and it was working.

Answer (score 1):

The new Specman mode was just posted in Cadence Shared code forum and can be find directly here:
http://www.cadence.com/community/forums/T/28436.aspx